# R session Aborted Arc.open() arcgisbinding

Tags: r, fatal-error

I've been having an issue where I try to open an ArcGIS shapefile through the 'arcgisbinding' package and my R session aborts. My code is:

```
library(tidyverse)
install.packages('arcgisbinding', repos='https://r.esri.com/', type='win.binary')
library(arcgisbinding)
arc.check_product() #check ArcGIS pro license
library(sf)

data<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\bsilve04\\Box\\Mato_ohitika\\Deliverables\\SDprimary2022_state.csv")

SDsenate.vote<-filter(data,RaceType == "STATE SENATOR" ) #divide state legislature into 2 DFs to account for slightly different geographies
SDhouse.vote<-filter(data,RaceType == "STATE REPRESENTATIVE" )

#load in shapefiles
SDsenate.shape.path<-arc.open(path = "H:\\Mato_ohitika\\Shapefiles\\tl_2020_46_sldu20\\tl_2020_46_sldu20.shp")
```

I've run this successfully before, but other times the R session just randomly aborts. Does anyone know a solution for this bug?

Comment: I've been having this problem as well when I try to open feature layers form ArcGIS Online.